# I need to provide a callback when instantiating a class from an API. How can I bind the instance itself to the callback, eagerly?

Tags: python, callback, closures, partial-application

I've encountered this problem with a few different major third-party libraries and frameworks now. Let me try to boil it down to the essentials:

- The API provides a class `Example`, where the constructor expects a `callback` parameter. When some event occurs (due to complex logic outside my control), the API will call the `callback` function.
- I have a function `modify` that accepts an instance of `Example` and calls various methods on it:

  ```
  def modify(it):
      it.enabled = True
      it.visible = True
      try:
           it.paint('black')
      except AProblemComesAlong:
           it.whip()
  ```
- I want to create an instance `x` of `Example`. When an event occurs that is associated with `x`, the `x` instance should be modified via `modify`.

Thus, I would like to bind `x` as an argument to `modify`, per [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/). The problem is, it doesn't exist yet, because I am still calling the constructor:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> x = Example(callback=partial(modify, x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Of course, I could avoid the `NameError` by allowing the `lambda` to look up the name later:

```
>>> x = Example(callback=lambda: modify(x))
```

but this [is late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/), so it doesn't work properly if e.g. [I'm in a loop and `instance` is the iteration variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop), or if `instance` is reassigned later for any other reason.

How can I accomplish early binding of `instance` to its own callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can try any of these approaches:

- Double-check if the API allows you to set the callback later (two-phase construction):

  ```
  from functools import partial
  instance = Example()
  # Read the documentation and see if Example provides something like:
  instance.callback = partial(modify, instance)
  # or possibly they didn't think of using a decorator for their validation logic:
  instance.set_callback(partial(modify, instance))
  ```
- Subclass the example so that it calls the callback from its own method, and adjusts the construction arguments to use that method as a wrapper:

  ```
  from functools import partial

  class ContextProvidingExample(Example):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          try:
              my_callback = kwargs['callback']
              kwargs['callback'] = partial(my_callback, self)
          except KeyError:
              pass
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

  Credit @tdelaney for the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62868723/523612).
- If the flexibility isn't needed, the `modify` logic could be integrated directly into the subclass instead:

  ```
  class SelfModifyingExample(Example):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if 'callback' in kwargs.keys():
              raise ValueError('cannot override callback')
          kwargs['callback'] = self._modify
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      def _modify(self):
          self.enabled = True
          self.visible = True
          try:
              self.paint('black')
          except AProblemComesAlong:
              self.whip()
  ```
- As a last resort, register instances in a dictionary, and arrange for the callback to look them up by name:

  ```
  from functools import partial

  hey_you = {} # say my name...
  def modify_by_name(name):
      modify(hey_you[name]) # call modify() maybe?
  # Let's use a simple wrapper to make sure instances get registered.
  def stand_up(name):
      result = Example(callback=partial(modify_by_name, name))
      hey_you[name] = result
      return result

  who = what = stand_up('slim shady')
  ```

  This way is a bit clunky, but you may find the string name for instances useful elsewhere in the code.